# Returning the first two odd numbers in an array

Tags: javascript, numbers, return

I have to run a code that picks out the odd numbers in an array, and returns the first two odd numbers in that array. I've figured out how to return all of the odd numbers from the array, just not the first two.

code so far:

```
function oddCouple(_numberList) {
  let numberList = [5, 2, 3, 1];
  let oddNumbers = numberList.filter((number) => number % 2 !== 0);

  console.log(oddNumbers);
}
oddCouple();
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

[Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) returns the selected number of items from the array starting from a specified index.

```js
function oddCouple(_numberList) {
  let oddNumbers = _numberList.filter((number) => number % 2 !== 0).slice(0, 2);

  console.log(oddNumbers);
}
oddCouple([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]);
```

Comment: this is good, but it may run through all the array, which could be big

Answer (score 2):

You can use `for..of` loop, and `break` when the array contains 2 items like so:

```js
function oddCouple(_numberList) {
  let numberList = [5, 2, 3, 1];
  let arr = [];
  for(let number of numberList) {
    (number % 2) !== 0 && arr.push(number);
    if(arr.length === 2) break;
  }

  console.log(arr);
}
oddCouple();
```

Answer (score 2):

The built in method would be [`Array.slice`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp). This code would be suitable for a small arrays.

For larger arrays it would be more efficient to manually loop through the source array so you are only evaluating the modulus operation for the first N odd numbers.

Additionally, division is expensive. You can check if a number is odd using the binary `&` operator; e.g.: `(number & 1) == 1`

```js
function oddCouple(_numberList) {
  let numberList = [5, 2, 3, 1];
  let oddNumbers = numberList.filter((number) => (number & 1) == 1).slice(0,2);

  console.log(oddNumbers);
}
oddCouple();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function oddCouple(_numberList) {
  let numberList = [5, 2, 3, 1];
  let oddNumbers = numberList.filter((number) => number % 2 !== 0).slice(0,2);

  console.log(oddNumbers);
}
```

Comment: Looking at the OP's post, they might be new to coding or at least to JS, so an explanation of what you are doing here might be helpful